# Userscript to autofill jQuery UI Datepicker - wrong date format

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to autofill a [jQuery UI datepicker](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/), but the date is being pasted in `MM/DD/YYYY` format. I need it to be pasted in `yy-mm-dd` format. When the native datepicker functionality is used, the date is filled correctly. I'm attempting to set the date using the following methods, but each fills in the wrong format. How can I properly set the date in `yy-mm-dd` format instead of the default `MM/DD/YYYY` format?

The page uses jQuery 2.1.4 and jQuery UI 1.11.4.

```
// initialize date
var cur = new Date();

// methods I've tried
$('.selector').datepicker('setDate', cur);

$('.selector').datepicker('formatDate', 'yy-mm-dd');
$('.selector').datepicker('setDate', cur);

$('.selector').datepicker('option', 'formatDate', 'yy-mm-dd');
$('.selector').datepicker('setDate', cur);

$('.selector').datepicker('option', 'formatDate', 'yy-mm-dd');
$('.selector').datepicker('refresh');
$('.selector').datepicker('setDate', cur);

// from answers below
$('.selector').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
$('.selector').datepicker('setDate', cur);

// this method changes the format displayed in the field, but the form's
// validation throws an error that it is in the wrong format. focus/unfocus
// on the field manually after this sets the date back to the previous format.
$('.selector').datepicker('setDate', cur);
var s = cur.getFullYear() + '-' + (('0' + (cur.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)) +
        '-' + (('0' + (cur.getDate())).slice(-2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".selector").datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
```

Comment: Unfortunately did not work. Added it to my post to indicate that it didn't.

Comment: have you added jquery.ui file along with jquery file?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.selector').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
var curFormatted = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', cur);
$('.selector').datepicker('setDate', curFormatted);
```

Comment: On the second line, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatDate' of undefined(…)`. I'm not sure if this is a problem with the native version of jQuery UI or if I did something wrong.

Comment: What versions of jquery and jquery-ui are you using?

Comment: jQuery 2.1.4 and jQuery UI 1.11.4. Added to the question for reference as well.

Comment: Do `$('.selector').datepicker('setDate', s);` instead of `$('.selector').datepicker('setDate', cur);` after setting the date format

Answer (score 0):

I feel silly, but the site actually uses [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker), not the jQuery UI datepicker. I sincerely apologize.